# JQuery Draggable and Resizeable over IFrames (Solution)

Tags: jquery, iframe, draggable, resizable

I recently ran into some troubles using JQuery Draggable and Resizable plugins. Looking for solutions, i found some very fragmented code in many different places and finally filed down to a clean solution which seems to work almost perfectly for me.

I thought i'd share my findings for anyone else, should they come accross this issue too.

I have a div which contains and IFrame. This div must be resizeable and draggable. Simple enough - add the jquery draggable and resizable to the div like so:

```
$("#Div").draggable();
$("#Div").resizable();
```

All is fine until you drag over another div containing an iframe or try to resize your current div, by moving over your current iframe. Both functions stop when over an iframe.

Solution:

```
$("#Div").draggable({
    start: function () {
        $(".AllContainerDivs").each(function (index, element) {
        var d = $('<div class="iframeCover" style="zindex:99;position:absolute;width:100%;top:0px;left:0px;height:' + $(element).height() + 'px"></div>');
        $(element).append(d);});
    },
    stop: function () {
        $('.iframeCover').remove();
    }
});



$("#Div").resizable({
    start: function () {
        $(".AllContainerDivs").each(function (index, element) {
            var d = $('<div class="iframeCover" style="z-index:99;position:absolute;width:100%;top:0px;left:0px;height:' + $(element).height() + 'px"></div>');
            $(element).append(d);
        });
    },
    stop: function () {
        $('.iframeCover').remove();
    }
});
```

Enjoy!

PS: Some extra code to create windows which, when selected, are brought to the front of the other draggables:

In the draggable start function -

```
var maxZ = 1;
$(".AllContainerDivs").each(function (index, element) {
    if ($(element).css("z-index") > maxZ) {
        maxZ = $(element).css("z-index");
    }
});
$(this).css("z-index", maxZ + 1);
```

Comment: Also JQuery UI dialogs are a very simple way to get floating iframe on the page:)

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddler of this or something, so i can see it in context? I'm not sure how you have your html setup, so your selectors don't make any sense to me. Thanks

Comment: Heh. So simple and yet works so well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of ways to achieve this, all depending on your needs. I found resizing/dragging many windows slows the UI down a lot, and as such I ended up hiding the iframes on start of resize/Drag with a border to help navigation.

There are some jquery plugins that achieve part of this functionality, but many struggle with iframes.

The bring to front can also be improved at points and may not work in all situations.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, a simple call to `$('iframe').toggle()` on `start` and `stop` (see the other answers for examples on setting those callbacks) is all that's needed.

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
 $('#Div').draggable({ iframeFix: true });
```

This should work.

Comment: This was the first thing I tried and it fails under multiple conditions, I'm not sure why, because essentially its the same thing I've implemented.

Comment: Actually it disabled links within the draggable element for some reason, ended up doing this instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5646590/1342440

Comment: try to understand my feeling when i struggled with this bug for an hour and finally i found this solution, `iframeFix: true` - how obvious. saved my day. thanks!

Answer (score 5):

What I've done is define `body.dragging iframe {pointer-events: none;}` then add `dragging` class to body on dragstart event and remove it on dragend event.

Works fine for me, not sure why it wasn't mentioned before, as far as I can tell pointer-events CSS property was already around in 2010.

Answer (score 1):

I first also went like Byron Cobb's solution, but as I'm using a dialog element and the Iframe isn't needed when the dialog is shown (it's a saving dialog), I liked using the [modal](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-modal) option:

```
$('#savingDialog').dialog({
    modal: true
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why so hard? There is much more beautiful solution:

- put your iframe inside relative div with some z-index, say 0
- make iframe relative also and change it's z-index to -1 during dragging:

code:

```
$("#Div").draggable({
    start: function () {
        $("iframe").css('z-index', '-1');
    },
    stop: function () {
        $("iframe").css('z-index', '0');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

All great answers, but none were easily implemented for me!

I was helped, but in the end, I used:

Inside the Iframe Header `<script>` tag:

```
var iframes = window.parent.$('iframe');
iframes.each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('src') == '<YOUR SOURCE PATH>')
    $(this).css('z-index', '-1');
});
```

This is to fix a TinyMCE IFrame Draggable issue. on applying this code inside the iframe, the Non-Draggable problem. Also, check the order of the *.js files, it makes a difference!