# jQuery Draggable IFrameFix

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a little problem with the jQuery Draggable IFrameFix.
I have a container (as shown below) with an iframe inside of it. I turned on the iframeFix in my draggable setup, but it doesn't change a thing. Anyone who had the same problem or anyone who might know how to solve this?

```
<div class="container">
<div class="toolbar">
    <div class="opt1"></div>
    <div class="opt2"></div>
</div>
<iframe src="url" class="frame" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"><p>No support for iframes</p></iframe>
</div>
```

This if my javascript code.

```
$(".container").draggable({
        snap: ".snapper_col",
        containment: "#element_container",
        handle: '.opt1',
        snapTolerance: 20,
        iframeFix: true,
        cursor: "crosshair",
        start: function(ev,ui){
        },
        drag: function(ev,ui){

        },
        stop: function(ev, ui){

        }
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solved it.

I created my own overlay over my iframe and when I start dragging I display it and hide it when I stop. This way the iframe doensn't mess with the dragging.

Comment: thank you so much for sharing that tip. I am using jQuery UI dialog with IFRAME and it was causing endless problems.

Comment: Doing the same now. It was also reported as a bug here: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7650

Comment: @sirwilliam, I coded out Jeroenjoosen's answer. Thanks for the solution, it works. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24597136/1342440

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can put a div over the iframe, i use this function:

```
div.draggable{ 
    cancel: '.noDraggable',
    scroll: false,
            appendTo: 'body',
            zIndex: 9999,
            cursor: "move",
            distance: 10,
            iframeFix: true,

            start: function(){
            var iframe = $(this).find("iframe");
                if(iframe.length > 0){
                div(iframe.parent(), "img/blank.gif", "transparent");  
                }
            },


            stop: function(){
                $(this).find(".capaCargando").remove();
            }

});
```

And this is the function

```
function capaCargando(div, img, color){
                                if(div.length > 0){
                                    //div.find('.capaCargando').remove();
                                    //aLaConsola(div.find('.capaCargando').length);
                                    if(img == undefined){
                                        img = 'img/uispoty/loadBusqueda.gif';
                                    }

                                    if(color == undefined){
                                        color = '#666';
                                    }

                                    var w = div.width(),
                                    h = div.height(),
                                    html = "<div class='capaCargando'>"+
                                    "<div class='bgCapaCargando' style='background-color:"+color+"'></div>"+
                                    "<div class='iconoCapaCargando' style='background-image:url("+img+")'></div>"+
                                    "</div>";
                                    div.prepend(html);
                                    var capa = div.find(".capaCargando");
                                    capa.find(".bgCapaCargando, .iconoCapaCargando").width(w).height(h);
                                }
                           }
```

You need study this code because i use this for my project, with clases and other things, but sure you understand the concept.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code to illustrate the correct answer given by [jeroenjoosen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/563667/jeroenjoosen) located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5646590/1342440)

**CSS**

```
.frameOverlay {
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     background: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.5); // transparent is an option or a color
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     display: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="frameOverlay"></div> <!--place anywhere within the body -->
```

**Jquery**

```
<script>
      $(function() {
        $( "#draggable" ).draggable({
            start: function() {
                $('.frameOverlay').fadeIn('fast');
            },
            stop: function() {
                $('.frameOverlay').fadeOut('fast');
            }
        });
      });
</script>
```