# Jquery - Resizing or dragging a DIV with an iframe inside

Tags: jquery, youtube, draggable

Try to resize the DIV in this example -> http://jsbin.com/ixesak/edit#preview

The cursor moves over the Youtube-Player (while resizing or dragging) and the result is that the resize function stops. 
Hope someone can help me.

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{  
  $('#test').draggable().resizable(); 
});
```

**HTML**

```
  <div id="test" style="padding:20px; background-color:#f00;">
  <iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="100%" height="100%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/NugRZGDbPFU?autoplay=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  </div>
```

**update:** A solution, but maybe not the best?
http://jsbin.com/ixesak/7/edit

Comment: The problem isn't related to the youtube-player but the iframe. Try using any other website and the problem is still there.

Comment: @Jason Gennaro, try to resize the div very fast.

Comment: @Simon Skov Boisen, You are right! Any ideas for a "workaround"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[drag iframe example](http://jsbin.com/ixesak/10/edit#preview)

make the iframeFix be an overlay over the iFrame, since the iframe is taking over the mouse events. Set the width and height ot the iframeFix, so that the handle for the resize can be visible and make the other necessary css staff as you need them to be..

```
<div id="cont" style="height:1000px; width:1000px; background-color:grey;">
    <div id="test" style="padding:20px; background-color:#f00;">
        <div id="iframeFix" style="display:block; background:transparent; position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; z-index:9999999;"></div>
        <iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="100%" height="100%" style="z-index:2000!important;" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/NugRZGDbPFU?autoplay=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627217/jquery-draggable-and-resizeable-over-iframes-solution)

Here is what worked for me

```
$('#Div').draggable({ iframeFix: true });
```